# Firebase ML Kit Custom Model Inference from Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-mlkit

I was hoping to build a Firebase Cloud Function for inferring/interpreting on a Custom Model hosted in ML Kit.

The [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models) has some pretty in-depth detail on inference for Android and iOS, but I'm hoping this is possible from Cloud Functions (node) as well.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase ML Kit is exclusively for mobile devices, not backends like Cloud Functions.  If you want to work with ML on a backend, consider using something else, such as [AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/automl/).

Comment: Any chance this feature is still coming? It would be nice if I could do everything inside Firebase.

Comment: If I wanted to use Firebase ML kit for moderation purposes then using it client-side seems like a risk, no?  Never trust the client, right?